# urlize() in Doctrine_Inflector Class in Doctrine 2 / Symfony 2?

Tags: doctrine-orm, slug, urlize

I was looking for a built-in method to urlize/slugify a string, instead of copying a strandard one found on google.

Thus I found this : http://sourcecookbook.com/en/recipes/59/call-the-slugify-urlize-function-from-doctrine , referencing to this Doctrine Class http://www.tig12.net/downloads/apidocs/symfony/lib/plugins/sfDoctrinePlugin/lib/vendor/doctrine/Doctrine/Doctrine_Inflector.class.html , with the method `urlize()` which is exactly what I'm looking for.

But, in my Doctrine Bundle from Symfony 2, in `\vendor\doctrine\common\lib\Doctrine\Common\Util` my Inflector class is pretty empty.

What happened to this `urlize()` method ? Do I have to recode it ?

Answer (score 2):

There's https://github.com/Behat/Transliterator which includes the urlize function from Doctrine1

> This is the part taken from Doctrine 1.2.3
>   Doctrine inflector has static methods for inflecting text

You could just `composer require behat/transliterator`
and have a HelperClass extending `Behat\Transliterator`.

And then be able to do: `MyStringHelper::urlize("isn't that great?")`

Answer (score 1):

The file you are looking at (Doctrine\Common\Util\Inflector) is supposed to be used internally by Doctrine, to convert between table names (underscore separated), property names (camelCase), and class names (CamelCase).

What you are looking for can be achieved with the [sluggable](https://github.com/l3pp4rd/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/sluggable.md) doctrine extension. You can ingtegrate it easily into a symfony2 application with [stof/StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle](https://github.com/stof/StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle).

Comment: Well, I guessed it was used internally by Doctrine, but I wanted to use it anyway so I don't duplicate any code.

Actually, I don't want to add an extension just for one basic function.. So I think I'll make my own class/function !